# Default menu item undo

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu, menu-item

I have accidentally set a single article menu item to be the default page of my site. So that page now acts as the site home page.

In the menu manager for the Main Menu, that menu item now has a gold star in the Home column. I cannot undo this.

When I open the menu item and try to change the Default Page setting back to No and Save, I get an error: 'At least one menu item has to be set as Default'.

Of course that would be the original Home page. But I can't see how I can access the setting to make the home page default again. I have a custom template for the home page.

How can I reset my home page?[image]

[image]

Comment: don't know if it will help. I have two pages I use as my home page. One if I have something special on and a standard one. Any article as far as I know can be set to be the home page.

Answer (score 5):

You can't "unset" the default page. As you mention, Joomla requires at least one menu item to be set as default.

The solution is to set any other menu item as the default page by clicking the grey star (or setting "Default Page" to "Yes"). This will remove the star from the other menu item automatically.

[image: Set default menu item]

[image]

### Update:

According to your screenshot (and as @Igor pointed out in his answer) you're trying to assign a menu item alias as default homepage. This is not possible, that's why the star is ont there. Try using the menu item that this alias is *pointing to*, it should have a star. You can leave the "Home" menu item as it is if needed.

Comment: That is not the problem. I know how to do that.

Comment: Then what's the problem? Maybe I didn't understand your question entirely, but if you can explain or add a screenshot I'm sure there is a solution

Comment: The problem is that the menu item I need to make default (I think) does not have a gray star in the home column in the menu manager. There is no option for making it the default page. Some menu items do not have that option ; i.e. text separator. So where is the menu item I need select to restore the Home Page? Is it not the home menu? I can't put in a screen shot because this is a comment. I will have to edit original post

Comment: It does not have a grey star because its menu type is "Menu item alias". You can't set a menu of type "Menu item alias" as default home page, as Igor Pereira already answered.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: I know, its just an example. I can't find the right menu item.

Comment: You've got several answers to what your questions seems to be. If you can't find the right menu item, how do you know it has no grey star?

Comment: There is no way to revert to your old menu entry, like an undo function in Word for example. You have to find your old home menu entry and set it as the new default, like johanpw showed you.

Comment: The menu item the alias is pointing to is home and I can't make it default

Comment: So your menu item "Home" is pointing to "Home"?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot set a Menu Item Alias as Default Home Page

Comment: I know that, just an example. No one is answering the question.

Comment: @clarland go to your Menu Item Home and see which menu he is pointing.
Go to this Menu Item and set has home page.

Comment: The menu item alias is pointing to the menu item Home which does not have a star next to it so it cannot be made the default page. There is something else going on.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution. I was right. The Home menu item was the correct item to select as the original home page / default menu item.

**The question I should have asked myself was:**

> When I made the single article item into the default menu item, what
>   did Joomla do with the old home page???

**Answer:**

> It turned it into something else.

Usually you don't have a single article as your home page. The home page is just the origin of the site navigation. So Joomla changed the menu type into a menu item alias!

So the solution was to turn the menu type back into what it originally was: a featured article. Then you have restored the abitilty to make it the default menu item again. The reason I could not find the item that the alias was pointing to was that it wasn't pointing to anything.

[image]

Comment: Joomla is not changing a menu item type by itself - especially just because you changed the default menu item.

Comment: This is wrong: The question I should have asked myself was: when I made the single article item into the default menu item, what did Joomla do with the old home page??? Answer: it turned it into something else.

Comment: 'Usually you don't have a single article as your home page'. - Usually you can have any kind of components menu items as a home page - and Joomla will not make any changes to your any previous home menu items.